# How do I allow access to userdir on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, apache2, lamp

I've just installed a fairly vanilla LAMP stack on 12.10 (via `apt-get install mysql-server phpmyadmin`) on my laptop for development purposes.

I've enabled mod_userdir and restarted Apache, but trying to access a url under `http://localhost/~username/` just gives me 403 Forbidden.  Accessing `http://localhost` works fine.

I've installed similar setups lots of times on previous Ubuntu versions, but never come across this problem.  Do I need to do something special to allow access?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to do `sudo chmod 711 /home/username` as explained [in this thread at Linux-Noob.com](http://www.linux-noob.com/forums/index.php?/topic/406-userdir-kept-getting-403-forbidden/)